# Deserialize Json.net in VB.net for an array of an array

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I need to deserialize an API response using Json.net in VB.net

A few notes,

- I must use VB for this project.  I was able to at least force an upgrade to .net4.8
- I have no control over the API response, and I will not be able to get the vendor to update it.
- In the end, I need the values and text for each of the choices to write to a data table for a repeater.

This is the api response:

```
{"choiceLists": [
    [
        {
            "value": "1",
            "text": "Radio_Test"
        },
        {
            "value": "2",
            "text": "Text_Test"
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            "value": "1",
            "TEXT": "Choice 1"
        },
        {
            "value": "2",
            "position": "Choice 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to deserialize into this structure:

```
Public Class SurveyChoices

    Public Class ChoiceLists
        Public Property choicelist As ???? <- what to do here?
    End Class

    Public Class Choice
        Public Property value As String
        Public Property TEXT As String
    End Class

End Class
```

Here's the line to deserialize:

```
ResponseText = str.ReadToEnd()
survey = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of SurveyChoices)(ResponseText)
```

Can I modify the choicelist property in my ChoiceLists class in such a way that Json.net will read it?

I've tried a few different ways to define choicelist.  Every way I've defined it the deserializer does the same thing, it just outputs the json string as a generic object to choicelists.

Comment: It's `List(Of List( Of Choice))` -- BTW, your JSON has an extra comma and is missing a closing square bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.Net has two legal syntaxes for this:

```
Public Property choicelist()() As Choice
```

and

```
Public Property choicelist As Choice()()
```

Comment: The first syntax did not work, it gave me an error of "End of Statement Expected"  But the second syntax worked and got me where I needed to be!  Thank you!